# javax.smartcardio SCARD_SHARE_SHARED and SLEE4442 delay

Tags: java, smartcard, smartcard-reader

With "javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal" I can't to connect smartcard with SCARD_SHARE_SHARED parameter...The method to connect has not that parameter...

`public abstract Card connect(String protocol) throws CardException`

*Establishes a connection to the card. If a connection has previously established the specified protocol, this method returns the same Card object as the previous call.
Parameters:
protocol - the protocol to use ("T=0", "T=1", or "T=CL"), or "*" to connect using any available protocol.*

Is there any way to perform that sharemode connecting smarcard with javax.smartcardio?

I have a delay problem connecting SLEE4442 smartcard (15-20 seconds after card is inserted) and I think that connecting with SHARED MODE may be the clue.

Answer (score 1):

With Java's SmartcardIO, connections to smartcards are opend with `SCARD_SHARE_SHARED` by default, so you should already be connected in shared mode.

You can then use `Card.beginExclusive()` to re-open that connection in exclusive mode (`SCARD_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE`).

Or you can open the connection in direct mode (`SCARD_SHARE_DIRECT`) using:

```
card = terminal.connect("direct");
```

But in that mode you would also need to manually set the communication protocol using IOCTL commands before you could send APDUs to the card.

Comment: please which smartcardio method to send IOCTLs ?